# Sql Conditional Not Null Constraint

Tags: sql, constraints, notnull

I am curious to know is it possible to create a conditional not null constraint in sql? In otherwords is it possible to create a constraint such that a column B can be null as long column A contains lets say 'NEW' but if the contents of column A changes to something else then column B is no longer allowed to be null? 
And to extend on that, it is then possible to make it so that column B must be null or empty as long as column A says 'NEW'?
Thanks All :D

Comment: FWIW, I don't think most database designers would call this a conditional constraint. *I'd* probably just call it a constraint, but if I had to qualify it more, I might call it a multi-column constraint or a multi-column CHECK() constraint. It's standard SQL.

Comment: @Catcall: Chris Date quote: "such constraints are sometimes referred to, informally, as tuple constraints, or row constraints in SQL—though this latter term is also used in SQL to mean, more specifically, a row constraint that can't be formulated as a column constraint... All such usages are deprecated, however, because constraints constrain updates and... there's no such thing as a tuple or row level update in the relational world."

Comment: @onedaywhen: I don't have the current edition. In the 7th edition, what I'm seeing here (apart from NULL) looks like what he calls a relvar constraint (p253). It accommodates multiple columns, and he says it can be arbitrarily complex (meaning, I suppose, that it could refer to other relations, views, aggregates, and phases of the moon).

Comment: @Catcall: [SQL and Relational Theory: How to Write Accurate SQL Code](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=WuZGD5tBfMwC&pg=PA174&lpg=PA174&dq=%22a+row+constraint+that+can't+be+formulated+as+a+column+constraint%22&source=bl&ots=WepZ-rBKHD&sig=Za4O9W5q6mZ1BQsaoCdLx5J6jmQ&hl=en&sa=X&ei=mVKWT4aSA8mW-wbYhPT9DQ&ved=0CCUQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22a%20row%20constraint%20that%20can't%20be%20formulated%20as%20a%20column%20constraint%22&f=false)

Comment: In that paragraph, he also says, "Note in particular that it can be checked for a given supplier tuple by examining just that tuple in isolation--there's no need to look at any other tuples in the relvar or any other relvars in the database." (Sounds like a good thing.) I *think* "all such usages" refers to "a row constraint that can't be formulated as a column constraint", not to a column constraint that refers to other columns. But I could be wrong.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

This is perfectly fine for CONSTRAINT CHECK. Just do this:

Requirement:

> is it possible to create a constraint such that a column B can be null
>   as long column A contains lets say 'NEW' but if the contents of column
>   A changes to something else then column B is no longer allowed to be
>   null?

Note the phrase: column B **can** be null

Solution:

```
create table tbl
(
    A varchar(10) not null,
    B varchar(10),

    constraint uk_tbl check
    (
      A = 'NEW' -- B can be null or not null: no need to add AND here
      OR (A <> 'NEW' AND B IS NOT NULL)
    )
);
```

You can simplify it further:

```
create table tbl
(
    A varchar(10) not null,
    B varchar(10),

    constraint uk_tbl check
    (
      A = 'NEW' 
      OR B IS NOT NULL
    )
);
```

---

Requirement mutually incompatible to requirement above:

> And to extend on that, it is then possible to make it so that column B
>   must be null or empty as long as column A says 'NEW'?

Note the phrase: column B **must** be null

```
create table tbl
(
    A varchar(10) not null,
    B varchar(10),

    constraint uk_tbl check
    (
      (A = 'NEW' AND B IS NULL)
      OR A <> 'NEW'
    )
);
```

Could be simplified with this, simpler but might not be as readable as above though:

```
create table tbl
(
    A varchar(10) not null,
    B varchar(10),

    constraint uk_tbl check
    (
      A <> 'NEW'
      OR B IS NULL
    )
);
```

Comment: I believe the only modern SQL dbms this *won't* work on is MySQL. MySQL doesn't enforce CHECK() constraints. (Question is tagged "SQL", so a comment seemed relevant.)

Comment: I just infer he's using Sql Server, I checked some of his questions. Most database questions aren't tagged specifically, and oughta be. If possible, I want stackoverflow not to accept sql tag, so everyone could be more specific on what RDBMS they are using

Comment: That constraint check is already working on Sql Server since day 1, likewise on Postgresql. I tested that DDL on both SQL Server and Postgresql, both of them accept it

Comment: Re your first SQL statement: the definition for `uk_tbl` is not a valid expression.

Comment: ...but otherwise agree your 'simpler' rewritten constraints, so +1 (see my answer for a different approach to the same answer :)

Comment: @Catcall: I mistakenly deleted the `OR` on the first check constraint when I removed superfluous parenthesis. Corrected it now. Thanks

Comment: If one day, you encounter a need for allowing *multiple nulls* (ANSI SQL-compliant) on a unique column in SQL Server, this might come in handy: http://www.ienablemuch.com/2010/12/postgresql-said-sql-server2008-said-non.html

Answer (score 2):

I think your first stated requirement is:

```
IF ( B IS NULL ) THEN ( A = 'NEW' )
```

Apply the implication rewrite rule:

```
IF ( X ) THEN ( Y )   <=>   ( NOT ( X ) OR ( Y ) )
```

In your case;

```
( NOT ( B IS NULL ) OR ( A = 'NEW' ) )
```

Minor rewrite to take advantage of SQL syntax:

```
( B IS NOT NULL OR A = 'NEW' )
```

---

Your second stated ("extend") requirement:

```
IF ( A = 'NEW' ) THEN ( B IS NULL )
```

Apply rewrite rule:

```
( NOT ( A = 'NEW' ) OR ( B IS NULL ) )
```

Minor rewrite:

```
( A <> 'NEW' OR B IS NULL )
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit: as mentioned in the other answers, a CHECK is the best method, not the trigger I originally suggested. Original text follows:

---

As dbaseman suggests, <s>triggers are the way to go</s> (not so). Try something like this (untested):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER test
  BEFORE UPDATE ON table1
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (new.A = 'NEW' and new.B IS NOT NULL)
   RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (
     num=> -20001,
     msg=> 'B must be NULL for new rows (A = NEW)'
);
```

Comment: For clarity, this solution is for Oracle. dbaseman provides a solution for what I assume is MSSQL :)

Comment: Oracle supports tuple constraints (`CHECK`): declarative constraints should be chosen above procedural code (including triggers).

Answer (score 0):

Per *onedaywhen*, this answer is criminally wrong, and an abomination.  You can use a **CHECK** constraint.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188258.aspx

<s>There's not a way to make conditional constraints.  You should, however be able to do the job using a trigger.  That's what they're for.</s>

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx

```
CREATE TRIGGER MyTable.ConditionalNullConstraint ON MyTable.ColumnB
AFTER INSERT
AS
IF EXISTS (SELECT *
    FROM inserted
    WHERE A <> 'NEW' AND B IS NULL
    )
BEGIN
    RAISERROR ('if A is ''NEW'' then B cannot be NULL', 16, 1);
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
END;
GO
```

Note that in the query you'll want to reference **inserted** which is a special object that behaves like a table, and lets you reference the row(s) that caused the trigger.

Of course, in this example you'd need to handle **AFTER UPDATE** also to enforce the constraint, but that's the general idea.

Comment: "There's not a way to make conditional constraints" Huh? This can be handled by a tuple constraint (`CHECK`) and should be preferred over a trigger in this case.

Comment: @onedaywhen wow, I stand very corrected, thanks.  Check constraint:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188258.aspx