# Changing the condition of elements in sql table with the result of check constraint in the same table

Tags: sql, oracle11g

how to create a table with elements 
Login Id 
Password
Username

I have to create a table with username which can be null after inserting values for username and password and username should be not null before inserting values for loginId and password.

Is there any way that I can do to make this condition work while I create the SQL table ?

Comment: Look for Constraints

Answer (score 1):

A simple google research and i got an answer to your question. --> [Sql Conditional Not Null Constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10273750/sql-conditional-not-null-constraint)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want a `check` constraint:

```
alter table t add constraint chk_t_fields
    check (username is not null or (loginid is not null and password is not null));
```

This checks that one or the other columns have values.